# calling a function when AngularUI Bootstrap modal has been dismissed and animation has finished executing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular UI bootstrap modal and I ran into a bit of a problem.

I want to call a function when the bootstrap modal dismiss animation is finished. The code block below will call the cancel() function as soon as the modal starts to be dismissed - and NOT when the modal dismiss animation has finished.

Angular UI does not use events, so there is no 'hidden.bs.modal' event being fired (at least, not to my knowledge).

```
var instance = $modal.open({...});

instance.result.then(function(data) {
            return success(data);
        }, function() {
            return cancel();
        })
```

The cancel() block immediately runs when the modal starts to close. I need code to execute when the **closing animation** for the Bootstrap modal finishes.

How can I achieve this with angular UI?

Component for reference:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late but hope it still helps! You can hijack the uib-modal-window directive and check when its scope gets destroyed (it is an isolated scope directive). The scope is destroyed when the modal is finally removed from the document. I would also use a service to encapsulate the functionality:

**Service**

```
app.service('Modals', function ($uibModal, $q) {
  var service = this,
      // Unique class prefix
      WINDOW_CLASS_PREFIX = 'modal-window-interceptor-',
      // Map to save created modal instances (key is unique class)
      openedWindows = {};

  this.open = function (options) {
    // create unique class
    var windowClass = _.uniqueId(WINDOW_CLASS_PREFIX);

    // check if we already have a defined class
    if (options.windowClass) {
      options.windowClass += ' ' + windowClass;
    } else {
      options.windowClass = windowClass;
    }

    // create new modal instance
    var instance = $uibModal.open(options);

    // attach a new promise which will be resolved when the modal is removed
    var removedDeferred = $q.defer();
    instance.removed = removedDeferred.promise;

    // remember instance in internal map
    openedWindows[windowClass] = {
      instance: instance,
      removedDeferred: removedDeferred
    };
    return instance;
  };

  this.afterRemove = function (modalElement) {
    // get the unique window class assigned to the modal
    var windowClass = _.find(_.keys(openedWindows), function (windowClass) {
        return modalElement.hasClass(windowClass);
      });

    // check if we have found a valid class
    if (!windowClass || !openedWindows[windowClass]) {
      return;
    }

    // get the deferred object, resolve and clean up
    var removedDeferred = openedWindows[windowClass].removedDeferred;
    removedDeferred.resolve();
    delete openedWindows[windowClass];
  };

  return this;
});
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('uibModalWindow', function (Modals) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        Modals.afterRemove(element);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And use it in your controller as follows:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Modals) {
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    var instance = Modals.open({
      template: '<div class="modal-body">Close Me</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Close</a></div>'
    });

    instance.result.finally(function () {
      alert('result');
    });

    instance.removed.then(function () {
      alert('closed');
    });
  };
});
```

I also wrote a blog post about it [here](http://coderose.de/2015/12/20/removing-bootstrap-modal-in-angularjs/).

Comment: I hacked it using a timeout set to the time it takes for the animation to finish. I totally dislike that idea because if the time for the modal to close ever changes, then that timeout needs to be updated as well. This is a really neat solution! I will give it a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just wanted to say that the next version of UI-Bootstrap allows you to do something like this: `instance.closed.then(function() { ... }`. The problem I ran into is that the next release of angular-UI-Bootstrap will not support angular 1.3, which shuts my project out.